# pdf php download produces empty file

Tags: php, pdf

```
<?php
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=Booking.pdf');
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
readfile('http://mysite.com/Booking.pdf');
?>
```

why is the Booking.pdf file downloaded empty!??

mac and windows both say:
The file “Booking.pdf” could not be opened because it is empty.

checked google and stackoverflow, can't find relative info... has anyone experienced this before?

ps: I only found this forum post:'*The online issue is a bit off topic I think, but is generally due to loading the PDF to a server in the ASCII mode of FTP rather than binary. That creates a corrupt file. Be sure to turn on binary transmission*', but this is not true in this case as i can display the same pdf file in an iframe and it is not blank/empty.

Comment: Does your PHP install allow for URLs in file calls, e.g. is allow_url_fopen enabled? It has nothing to do with ascii-mode ftp - you'd still get the corrupted PDF contents if your code was working. corrupted ftp uploads still produce a non-zero-length file.

Comment: i am assuming you are right and reading elsewhere that i have to make a custom (allow_url_fopen=on) ini.php in my public_html but apparently this is a serious security risk...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change

```
  readfile('http://mysite.com/Booking.pdf');
```

To

```
  readfile(__DIR__ . '/Booking.pdf');
```

Example

```
$file = __DIR__ . '/test.pdf' ;
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=Booking.pdf');
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header("Content-length: ".filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```